# Wrapping the entire application with a "use client" marked provider in Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a small app in Next.js, and I've not quite wrapped my head around the client-side vs server-side rendering.

I've been working from [this great guide](https://www.misha.wtf/blog/supabase-auth-next-13-pkce) on setting up NextJS with Supabase.

According to [the Next.js doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#the-use-client-directive):

> Once "use client" is defined in a file, all other modules imported into it, including child components, are considered part of the client bundle

So if I'm using an `AuthProvider` to wrap the app (as in the guide), but that `AuthProvider` is marked `"use client"`, I'm wondering if the `{children}` in the layout are also automatically part of the client bundle.

My guess is "no", because they aren't children of the `AuthProvider`, just adjacent ReactElements (or something), but I'd appreciate someone confirming and clarifying the terminology for me.

```
// AuthProvider.tsx

"use client";

...
```

```
// layout.tsx

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <AuthProvider>
            {children}
        </AuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot call in a client component body a server component, but it's totally fine to pass it as part of its `props`, `children` being one possibility as you can read on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#nesting-server-components-inside-client-components).

For example, in the below code, because everything is directly called in the client component body, you can only have client components (notice the comments):

```js
'use client'
 
// This pattern will **not** work!
// You cannot import a Server Component into a Client Component.
import ExampleServerComponent from './example-server-component'
 
export default function ExampleClientComponent() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
 
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
 
      <ExampleServerComponent />
    </>
  )
}
```

But, as said above, you can pass server components to a client component as part of its `props`:

```js
'use client'
 
import { useState } from 'react'
 
export default function ExampleClientComponent({ children }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
 
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
 
      {children}
    </>
  )
}
```

```js
// This pattern works:
// You can pass a Server Component as a child or prop of a
// Client Component.
import ExampleClientComponent from './example-client-component'
import ExampleServerComponent from './example-server-component'
 
// Pages in Next.js are Server Components by default
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <ExampleClientComponent>
      <ExampleServerComponent />
    </ExampleClientComponent>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure about the answer

I had a similar situation couple of days ago & found a snippet of code that was of great benefit to me.

```
 import dynamic from "next/dynamic"
const NoSSRWrapper = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) => (
  <>{children}</>
)

export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(NoSSRWrapper), { ssr: false })
```

Then you can wrap any part of your application (or your entire app) with this wrapper which prevents SSR and guarantee a CS components.